# Gh-pages deployment starts to render, but errors 404

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, github-pages

I have tested my React pwa locally and am happy with the results, however, when I deployed to gh-pages I get a 404 error. Funny thing is, my site begins to render before going to the 404 page not found. I am at a loss as most of what I’ve read says this problem is due to the absence of an index.html file which is not the case here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://evandersloot.github.io/meet-app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in `api.js` line 68

```js
const results = await axios.get('https://dx9dq6q3th.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/get-auth-url');
const { authURL } = results.data;
return (window.location.href = authURL);
```

authURL seems to be `undefined`. So when it sets `window.location.href = undefined` it makes a request for `https://evandersloot.github.io/meet-app/undefined` and then github returns a 404 page.

Comment: Thank you! Once I found the error and defined authUrl, the page renders as it should.